# Finding the correct Web Server Base Folder URL - ArcGIS Viewer for Flex

Tags: flex, web, arcgis-flex-viewer, viewer, url

When getting started with ArcGIS Viewer for Flex I enter the following details;

Web Server Base Folder: 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\flexviewers

Web Server Base Folder URL: 
my machine name followed by the \flexviewers (can't provide http address here)

However, I receive the following error message;

Please check your Web Server Base Folder URL.

I can't understand why the URL I provided isn't correct.

I am running on Windows 7 and have turned on II 6 Management Capability and Management Console. Is it possible that I need to share the folder on the server and if so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe this question would be better answered here: http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/111-ArcGIS-Viewer-for-Flex

Comment: same problem! until now working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by checking my shared folder permissions in windows explorer.

- In windows explorer, navigate to 'C:\inetpub\' right click on the folder 'wwwroot' and choose "Share With...>Specific People"
- From the dropdown, choose 'Everyone', and set permission level to 'Read'.

This should fix the issue.